# How does in an experiment, Superconductor experiment shows reading of 0 resistance?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

I have a minor doubt in superconductivity. Say at critical temperature, resistance (resistivity) is 0, so do one measures it. Like at critical temperature, by measuring voltage we can say resistivity is 0, but as its shows no reading so how can we infer this conclusion.
Hope my question makes sense to reader, what I am trying to convey it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you measure the zero resistance in a superconductor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/651336/)